# How to represent a set of sets as a vector

Tags: clustering, feature-engineering

I'm pretty new to machine learning.

I know I can represent a set of discrete values as a vector of 0/1 values. For instance, in the set of features {a, b, c, d, e}, the subset containing `{a, c}` can be represented as `[1, 0, 1, 0, 0]` and the subset containing `{c, d, e}` can be represented as `[0, 0, 1, 1, 1]`, meaning I have as many dimensions as elements, which is workable when you have a finite (and small) number of elements.

But now, for a clustering task, I want to represent sets of sets, like, for instance, representing the set `{{a, c}, {c, d, e}}`. How can I do that? Here, the basic 0/1 approach won't work, as I'll have `2^n` possible combinations. What is the workaround, if any?

**Edit**: here is the transcription as a less abstract, more business problem. I want to find clusters of people according to the trips they made. A trip consists in a set of cities visited, and a set of transportation used. For instance, people might have visited cities in the set `{Rabat, Alger, Marrakech, Tunis, Hammamet}` with transportation such as `{car, plane, train}`. A trip could be `{Rabat, Marrakech, plane}` or `{Alger, Marrakech, Tunis, car, train}`. Note the order in which cities were visited, or the order in which vehicles were used, is not considered.

An example of the items I want to find clusters of could be a person having made those two trips, represented as `p1 = {{Rabat, Marrakech, plane}, {Alger, Marrakech, Tunis, car, train}}`.

Comment: To be sure I understand, for one observation you have a set of subsets as the observed data point?

Comment: yes @kbrose, `{{a, c}, {c, d, e}}` is one of the datapoints I want to clusterize.

Comment: You may benefit from a reformulation. What's the real, business problem?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Emre, I just made a detailed example.

Comment: And what would you do next? There is little benefit in just encoding the data, you need to be able to do meaningful computations, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are describing [one-hot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot) encoding. There is a slot for each element. If the element is present, the slot has a one, and if the element if not present, the slot has a zero.

Typically, people will encode orthogonal features in different dimensions. In your case, cities would be one dimension and transportation type would be another dimension. A given data point would be one-hot encoded in a matrix (a 2D collection of vectors). If you want to add people, you would another dimension. That would create a 3D tensor with each person in a row.

Another way to compress your data is to encode not the cities (nodes) but the path between the cities (edges). From that encoding, you can create a [Laplacian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix) that sets up [spectral clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_clustering). Since you have multiple transportation methods for the routes, you can create clusters with multi-dimensional spectral clustering.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not have a similarity measure for trips, two trips are different if the sets that represent the trips are different. So you can simply represent different trips by different numbers and represent a person's trips by a set of those numbers.